# Make a raspberry pi pico left click whe gpio pin is shorted

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, hid, raspberry-pi-pico

I would like to make a raspberry pi pico running circut python activate left mouse button activate when a GPIO pin is shorted

I already have the adafruit HID library installed
Adafruit CircuitPython 7.3.0

Comment: Your question, as written, lack necessary information for an answer. Like where, pray tell, is the mouse and what is it connected to? (I presume your mouse is plugged into a Pi which is connected to the pico) That said, questions such as this, that do not present direct programming problems are off-topic here and would be better asked on [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can you detect when the GPIO pin is shorted? And can you click the mouse?